# Can't call child component on button click

Tags: angular

I am using [ng-sidebar](https://github.com/arkon/ng-sidebar). I want to call a child component (sidebar) on click of a button. But I am not getting any result.

**Example:** [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-sidebar-wxgb5b)

**parent ts:**

```
export class AppComponent {
  _opened: boolean = false;

  _toggleSidebar() {
    this._opened = !this._opened;
  }
}
```

**parent html:**

```
<ng-sidebar-container style="height: 100vh;">
  <app-sidebar [opened]="_opened"></app-sidebar>

  <!-- Page content -->
  <div ng-sidebar-content>
    <button (click)="_toggleSidebar()">Toggle sidebar</button>
  </div>
</ng-sidebar-container>
```

**child html:**

```
<ng-sidebar [(opened)]="opened" position="right">
  <ul>
    <li>Menu Item</li>
    <li>Menu Item</li>
    <li>Menu Item</li>
  </ul>
</ng-sidebar>
```

**child ts:**

```
export class SidebarComponent {
  @Input() opened: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created forked with change. check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-sidebar-wbwjdh.

You just have to add `ng-sidebar` on component selector in app.component.html